# Compression (gzip) does not work in NestJS

Tags: compression, nestjs

Created a standard NestJS project using the command: `nest new project-name`. After that, I installed compression `npm i --save compression` and plugged it into the project.

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import * as compression from 'compression';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.use(compression());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

But the compression does not work, response does not have `gzip`.

[Response in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXQij.png)

I've already tried clearing the cache, restarting the browser, nothing works.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you can debug it by defining `DEBUG=compression*` env. var.

Answer (score 3):

First, install the following package:

```
npm i --save compression
```

In the `bootstrap function` in the **main.ts** file, apply the **compression middleware** as follow

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app: INestApplication = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  ...
  app.use(compression({
    filter: () => { return true },
    threshold: 0
  }));

  ...
  await app.listen(4100);
}
```

Then, you will see the result

[image]

##### Note

if your browser is open, first close it then opens it again

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> = Reload your current page, ignoring cached content.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing else works:

```js
  const expressApp = express();
  expressApp.use(compression());
  const expressAdapter = new ExpressAdapter(expressApp);
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, expressAdapter);
  await app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. Maybe I'm not running the project correctly with compression? I run it like this: `npm build  npm start:prod`

Answer (score 0):

you also should have "Cache-Control" header

for example:

```
@Header('Cache-Control', 'public,max-age=31536000')
```

because there is a check for this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfjCl.png